# What Rewards do you get for Challenges?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

In Dungeon Defenders you get a reward item after completing a challenge level.  Additionally, I have heard that Medium/Hard challenges give a different reward from Insane mode.  I'm trying to find out what rewards come from each challenge, and on each difficulty.

Comment: There are also rewards for killing the bosses.

Comment: I am aware of that.  But I'm looking specifically for information regarding challenge rewards, not just boss level rewards.

Comment: having such a list would be awesome.

Comment: i am also interested in such a list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the list from the [wiki](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/PC_Challenges).  This is a CW so anyone can update if it changes.

As far as I know, easy challenges have no rewards, and medium/hard challenges have the same rewards.

Weapon Types:

- Ap = Apprentice
- Sq = Squire
- Hu = Huntress
- Mo = Monk

No Towers Allowed:

- Medium & Hard: Defense Reconstructor (Ap)
- Insane: Mobile Moxie (Sq)

Unlikely Allies

- Medium & Hard: Ogre Safety Razor (Sq)
- Insane: Ogre's Childhood Toy (Mo)

Warping Core

- Medium & Hard: Warp Stabilizer (Mo)
- Insane: Crystal Tracker (Hu)

Raining Goblins

- Medium & Hard: Dancing Cavalier (Hu)
- Insane - Goblin Overlord's Charge (Ap)

Wizardry

- Medium & Hard: Staff of the High Wizards (Ap)
- Insane: The Heretic (Sq)

Ogre Crush

- Medium & Hard: The High Five (Sq)
- Insane: Ogre Party Hat (Mo)

Zippy Terror

- Medium & Hard: Wick Cutter (Mo)
- Insane: Kobold Douser (Hu)

Chicken

- Medium & Hard: The Incubator (Hu)
- Insane: Chanticleer's Chandelier (Ap)

Monster Fest

- Medium & Hard: Spirit Champion's Magebane (Ap)
- Insane: Magina's Last Glaive (Mo)

Assault

- Medium & Hard: Aggressor (Mo)
- Insane: Blasticus (Hu)

Treasure Hunt

- Medium & Hard: Knox Bow (Hu)
- Insane: Shambhala Ley Staff (Ap)

Death from Above

- Medium & Hard: Skyreaper (Mo)
- Insane: The Pinioner (Sq)

Moving Core

- Medium & Hard: Prepetual Motion (Ap)
- Insane: The Quiesence (Sq)

Halloween Spooktacular: Rewards are class based

- Easy: Weisgram (Ap), Couteau (Sq), Geier (Mo), Van Wolfenstein (Hu)
- Medium: Same, but more powerful
- Hard: Same as above, but more powerful (godly possible), and also the [special costumes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33685/how-do-i-access-the-new-halloween-map-content/33688#33688).
- Insane: Nosferatu(Mo), Sicarius(Hu), Mad Jack(Ap), Bone Cutter(Sq) also unlocks the special costumes.

Comment: Actually, the Halloween content is *not* limited time. Trendynet [has posted](http://forums.trendyent.com/showthread.php?10214-Hallowe-en-Content-Available-Forever&p=83406&viewfull=1#post83406) that it will be available forever. It'll become available for Open players Nov. 5th.