# How do I access the new Halloween map/content?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I haven't beat all the maps in regular, nor any challenges, but I'd like to see and play the new one if I can.

- where do I find the special map so I can unlock outfits?
- do I have to beat the regular maps first?
- Is the map available in both ranked and open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the new content, click on the big Download Content button on the main page.  There are 2 items for the Halloween special event.  The first is the Costume Pack, which gives you these costumes:

- Devil – Monk
- Mummy – Apprentice
- Pirate – Squire
- Witch – Huntress

These are already unlocked and you can edit your character from the character selection screen to pick them immediately.

The second DLC is the Mission Pack, which unlocks the Halloween Spooktacular challenge (in the challenges list).  If you complete this challenge on hard or insane, you can unlock the following costumes (depending on the class you beat it with) and a [class specific weapon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33572/what-rewards-do-you-get-for-challenges) as well:

- Ninja – Monk
- Vampire - Apprentice
- Death Knight - Squire
- Angel - Huntress

I do not think you have to beat the regular missions first, but I am unsure of this as I've alreayd do so.

**Update**

A recent patch has unlocked the content to Open players as well.  So it is now available to all.

Answer (score 1):

The content is currently ONLY available on Ranked Online games (IE: TrendyNet games). The first set of costumes and the halloween challenge map are then just available. if you beat the new challenge map on Insane then you unlock the second set of costumes.

Trendy has said that the content will eventually work in Open/Local games as well but it doesnt right now.